# Django on Heroku

Tags: django, postgresql, mongodb, heroku, couchdb

I am building a website which I host on Webfaction's most basic plan right now. However, today I got a message one of my processes was killed as it was consuming to much memory.

I anticipate much, much more use of memory and also need a bigger database then I have at webfaction so I looked into switching to another hosting and using webfaction just as dev server.

I looked into AWS EC2 but I think it would be too steep of a learning curve, and am more driven towards Heroku as I see it now.

However, the free version only gets you a 5mb PostgreSQL database. I need much more than that in the future, however not 2 GB the first paid plan offers immediately -- I can't pay $200/month in the beginning.

I got a couple of questions:

1. Is there an in between plan for databases in Heroku? If not, what's the rationale? -- I don't get it.
2. I see the MongoDB and CouchDB addons are way cheaper -- I understand they are nosql however and the Django ORM can't really handle it. How easy is it to leave my app as it is and make it work on mongodb or couchdb? (My Django app is now written for Postgres).
3. Is it possible for the meantime to deploy my Django app on Heroku and connect with my Webfaction postgresql database?

Thanks so much, I'm starting this thing but don't know any dev people that now these things.

Comment: I also keep getting these messages from Webfaction. Is django not memory efficient?

Comment: Yeah dunno, Its probably inefficiency in my code though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't answer all your questions but;

Did you miss the 20Gb Shared plan for $15 - the $200 are for dedicated DB instances not shared like the 5Mb and 20Gb.